# Problem while trying to set up distribution profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, provisioning-profile

I have downloaded from itunes connect the provisioning distribution and the distribution certificate for my app and executed them.

The problem is when i try to select for the "code signing" the distribution file, the computer doesn't let me because "profile doesn't match any valid certificate / private key pair in the default key chain" .

I went to "organizer" and i can see in the "devices/library/provisioning profiles" my provisioning distribution and it's status shows "Valid signing identity not found" and as the top it shows " Xcode could not find a valid private key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain".

I understood that i might need some key, could this be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Xcode 4 in the Organizer in the Devices tab (where you are) you can check the checkbox which says 'Automatic Device Provisioning' this will re-download your provisioning profiles.

The best part is that if you do not have a developer keychain installed, *it will create the certificates for you*. For distribution: Then you can go to the provisioning portal, add the right profile to the distribution certificate and sign away to the app store.

(If you have multiple accounts you can have a certificate for one account installed and re-download the certificate for another account.)

Recap:

1. Delete provisioning profile that is invalid
2. Delete certificate of dev account that is tied to invalid certificate
3. Click refresh button with 'automatic device provisioning' checked
4. Reconnect distribution certificate with distribution profile
5. Archive and sign for app store
6. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Before you request a provision profile (either development or distribution) you need a certificate. You get that by generating a certificate signing request on your machine, and then uploading the CSR to the portal. That process creates a key pair, and the public key is included in the CSR and eventually in the resulting certificate. You then download the certificate and add it to your keychain. Provision profiles that you create will depend on you having a valid certificate in your keychain.